# What is あっちゃう in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

My friend sent me an email saying her mobile phone is having problems. Specifically, she said this:

> 携帯{けいたい}の電池{でんち}が電話{でんわ}すると5分{ふん}でなくあっちゃうようになった

I get the overall meaning, which is that when she makes a call, the battery runs out of power after only 5 minutes.

However I can't parse `でなくあっちゃうようになった`, specifically the `あっちゃう` part.

What is going on here, and how is it different from　`携帯{けいたい}の電池{でんち}が電話{でんわ}すると5分{ふん}でなくなる`?

*(Please no overly technical linguistic terms. Thanks!)*

Comment: sounds like the contracted form of ~てしまう for ~なくあって. But I'm not sure if "~なくあって" should exist. (There is ~なくて,　~なかった, but I'm not sure if there is a past+て-form. To my current knowledge it's not possible to have both past and て-form simultaneously.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Flaw comments, this is a typo of `5分でなくなっちゃう`, which is a contracted form of `5分でなくなってしまう` 'unfortunately, runs out in five minutes'.